# JavaScript event not executed after manually modifying HTML field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input text field  that is automatically  populated whenever a user clicks on a specific button , however if the user  manually changes or deletes  the text from the field  , then function no longer  works whenever  button is re-clicked !

Code:

```js
/* The JavaScript function that should be re-executed */

function getUnixTime(){
  var date = new Date();
  var unixTime= date.getTime(); 
  var datepack = [unixTime, date];
  return datepack;
}

function setTimeUnix(elementId){
  var datepack = getUnixTime();
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.setAttribute("value", datepack[0]);
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML code for the button and input field -->

<button id="idButton4" onclick="setTimeUnix('idInput4')" type="button">
  Stop2
</button>
<input id="idInput4" type="text" value="0">
```

Solution: Using the Input Text value Property as Sudharsan  pointed.

```
function setTimeUnix(elementId){
var datepack=getUnixTime();
var element=document.getElementById(elementId);
element.value=datepack[0];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the code

```
element.setAttribute("value",datepack[0]);
```

try using

```
element.value = datepack[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer   it worked  perfectly !!,  so just  for my understanding  why does the method   element.setAttribute(attributename,attributevalue) didn’t succeed in changing the value ,  is the method not reliable  to use in input fields Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The element property value and value attribute are *not the same thing*.

document.getElementById(elementId).value = datepack[0];